# How can we remotely Debug C++ applications running on Linux Server?

Tags: c++, c

In Java

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n <other arguments>
```

allows us to

- Start an application and suspends it
- opens up a socket (dt_socket) using Java Debug Wire Protocol - Allows to debug remotely
- Hosted on 8000 port

We can run this on a remote Linux Server and yet debug it on our own Desktop (even Windows) environment using either Netbeans or IntelliJ or other feature rich IDEs.

Is something of the sorts possible in C++ with visual studio community/code ? If so how.

PS: I know of ddd (data display debugger) & gdb

Comment: Are you not allowed to just ssh and debug it?

Comment: Yes we can SSH it but using an IDE will be better

Comment: Have you looked at Visual C++ for Linux Development (Google it)? Available as an add-on for VS2015 and a standard component in VS2017.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can (using gdb).

Follow the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gnat_ugn_unw/Remote-Debugging-using-gdbserver.html).

There may be some IDE using gdb as backend.

Comment: At least mentioning `gdbserver` would be slightly better than just linking a description of it.

Comment: GDBserver is an answer !